# RxJs: How to use .shareReplay() to cache HTTP data?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've been searching for a way to cache HTTP data in Angular, and finally I decided to use `.shareReplay()` to achieve it. Moreover, I'd like to clear the cache manually or clear it whenever this `ReplaySubject` is out-of-date, cause I know that I can set a time duration for `.shareReplay()`.  What's the best practice to meet the two requirements above?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really use `shareReplay` to cache observable, flush cache and provide initial cache seed at the same time.

- `shareReplay` is fine to cache values using `ReplaySubject`
- to flush cache you would need some outer control to force resubscribe on underlying observable and reset `ReplaySubject`
- providing initial value could be done with `startWith` but that has a problem of emitting multiple values where you expect only one.

I think this is special case enough to go with custom operator and cache controller.

```js
const { defer } = require('rxjs/observable/defer');
const { AsyncSubject, Scheduler } = require('rxjs');

class Cache {
  get isExpired() {
    return this.scheduler.now() > this.expiration;
  }

  constructor(initialValue, maxTime = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, scheduler = Scheduler.queue) {
    this.isComplete = false;
    this.hasError = false;
    this.subject = null;
    this.maxTime = maxTime;
    this.scheduler = scheduler;
    this.expiration = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    if (typeof initialValue !== 'undefined') {
      this.subject = new AsyncSubject();
      this.subject.next(initialValue);
      this.subject.complete();
      this.isComplete = true;
      this.extendExpiration();
    }
  }

  extendExpiration() {
    this.expiration = this.scheduler.now() + this.maxTime;
  }

  preventExpiration() {
    this.expiration = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  }

  flush() {
    this.expiration = 0;
  }
}

function cachingOperator(cache = new Cache()) {
  let refCount = 0;
  let subscription;
  return function cacheOperation(source) {
    refCount++;
    if (!cache.subject || cache.hasError || cache.isExpired) {
      cache.hasError = false;
      cache.preventExpiration(); // prevent expiration before underlying observable completes
      cache.subject = new AsyncSubject();
      subscription = source.subscribe({
        next(value) { cache.subject.next(value); },
        error(err) {
          cache.hasError = true;
          cache.subject.error(err);
        },
        complete() {
          cache.isComplete = true;
          cache.extendExpiration();
          cache.subject.complete();
        },
      });
    }
    const innerSub = cache.subject.subscribe(this);
    return () => {
      refCount--;
      innerSub.unsubscribe();
      if (subscription && refCount === 0 && cache.isComplete) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    };
  };
}

const caching = cache => source => source.lift(cachingOperator(cache));
```

`Cache` object will hold state. Your code is responsible for instantiation and that gives you full control.

Usage:

```js
const myCache = new Cache({ result: 'initialValue' }, 1000); // initial value and cache time 1s

const request = httpService.get(url)
  .pipe(
    caching(myCache)
  );

request.subscribe(); // initial value

setTimeout(() => {
  request.subscribe(); // issues new request
  request.subscribe(); // cache request
  myCache.flush();
  request.subscribe(); // new request
}, 1100);
```

The API could be definitely improved and made more fit to your use-case, but I hope this provides rough idea about how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `startsWith` instead because this allows you to initialize your data with a local cache and later replace with more updated data.

Answer (score 1):

Saw this question while searching to a solution to a similar problem. I wasn't able to get it to work with just the shareReplay api, but wanted to share a rxjs only solution (tw: inTypescript) in case anyone can use it:

```
     private cache = {};
     private cacheProperty(key:string, prop:string, httpCall$:Observable<any>, expirationTime?: number): Observable<any>{
        if(!(key in this.cache && prop in this.cache[key])){
          const timer$ = timer(expirationTime)
          const clearCache = new Subject<void>()
          const clearCache$ = merge(timer$, clearCache.asObservable()).pipe(take(1))
          const cacheProp$ = httpCall$.pipe(shareReplay(1, 5000),takeUntil(clearCache$))
          clearCache$.subscribe(_=> delete this.cache[key][prop])
          this.cache[key] = Object.assign(!!this.cache[key] ? this.cache[key] : {} ,{[prop]:{call$:cacheProp$, clear:clearCache }})
        }
        return this.cache[key][prop].call
      }

      public clearPropCache(key:string, prop:string){
        this.cache[key][prop].clear.next()
      }
```

It is personalized to the project we are on which requires multiple "user" caches (split by key) as well as multiple types of cache(lets say for example, bio) denoted by the prop. You can pass in an expiration time as well as manually clear it with a void subject in the second.

We are also using angular, so the httpCall$ should come in the form of an observable returned from the HttpClient module haven't tried it with other sources.

I also found this article very helpful in creating and slimming down my solution: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html

Hope it helps anyone else working on simple caching solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Node version, to combine with es6 switch to `import` statements instead of `require`.

In factory you can replace Observable `of(v)` with your http request.

I am posting more likely to find out what feedback this approach will get, rather than sharing cutting edge solution.

```
const {of} = require('rxjs');
const {shareReplay, tap} = require('rxjs/operators');

const BUFFER_SIZE = 1;
const CACHE_EXPIRATION = 10; // in ms

const factory = v => of(v).pipe(
    tap(v => console.log(v, 'pre processing')),
    shareReplay(BUFFER_SIZE, CACHE_EXPIRATION),
);

const cache = {};

const get = id => {
    let guard = false;

    if (cache.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        cache[id].subscribe(v => {
            console.log(id, 'not expired');
            guard = true;
        });

        if (guard) {
            return cache[id];
        }

        console.log(id, 'expired');
    }

    console.log(id, 'creting new observble pipeline');
    cache[id] = factory(id);
    return cache[id];
};


get('1').subscribe(v => console.log(v, 'finall sub'));
setTimeout(() => get('1').subscribe(v => console.log(v, 'finall sub')), 5);
setTimeout(() => get('1').subscribe(v => console.log(v, 'finall sub')), 8);
```

Output:

```
1 creting new observble pipeline
1 pre processing
1 finall sub
1 not expired
1 finall sub
1 expired
1 creting new observble pipeline
1 pre processing
1 finall sub
```